# HTML form to call php and aspx

Tags: php, html

I designed a contact us page which sends information to our sales team. It sends email using PHP. Next step is to send same customer information to Sales Fusion CRM system.

In order to send same customer information to sales fusion software form needs to post to a specific URL:"" {e.g }

HTML FORM:
 (As of now)

**Question:**
How can I use two different action with in same html tag to send same information to PHP file and to sale fusion URL.

Answer (score 0):

A solution for you would be that the PHP file sends the information to the aspx site :)

something like this should work for you :)

```
$url = ''; // Your URL HERE
$ch = curl_init($url);

$fields_string = '';    
foreach ($post as $key => $value) {
    $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
}


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: How can I send this information with above function 

<input type=hidden name="Customer" value="abc">
<input type=hidden name="cke" value="def">
<input type=hidden name="ownerid" value="ghi">
<input type=hidden name="overwrite" value="jkl">
<input type=hidden name="TriggerID" value="b">
<input type=hidden name="PushExternal" value="1">

Comment: $post is refering to the sanitized data from $_POST (maybe even only the values you want to send to page2 (your aspx file)

Comment: @kaper how can I send this information from the curl function.
<input type=hidden name="Customer" value="c">
<input type=hidden name="cke" value="1">
<input type=hidden name="ownerid" value="6">
<input type=hidden name="overwrite" value="0">
<input type=hidden name="TriggerID" value="1951">
<input type=hidden name="PushExternal" value="1">


<label for="FirstName">FirstName</label><input  id="FirstName" maxlength="40" name="FirstName" size="20" type="text" /><br>


<label for="Email">Email</label><input  id="Email" maxlength="40" name="Email" type="text" />